# Codeception - pointing DB to MAMP MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, macos, codeception

Is there a way to point the DB module for Functional tests in codeception to your MAMP MySQL server rather than the built in server?

```
class_name: TestGuy
    modules:
        enabled: [Db, Filesystem, TestHelper]
        config:
          Db:
             dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb'
             user: 'root'
             password: 'root'
             dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
             populate: true
             cleanup: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Codeception uses PDO to connect to the database. It will pass the "dsn" string straight into the PDO constructor. Thus, according to http://www.php.net//manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php, your configuration should be the following in order to connect to the MAMP MySQL Server running on port 8889:

```
class_name: TestGuy
    modules:
        enabled: [Db, Filesystem, TestHelper]
        config:
          Db:
             dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=testdb'
             user: 'root'
             password: 'root'
             dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
             populate: true
             cleanup: false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed the issue for me. 
In MAMP I ticket the box "Allow network access to MySQL"
[image]

My dsn setting in codeception.yml is: 
dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=la51'

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this at all - might work for you too..

```
class_name: TestGuy
modules:
enabled: [Filesystem, TestHelper, WebHelper, PhpBrowser]
config:
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://localhost/yourapp/'
        curl:
             CURL_RETURNTRANSFER: true
```

Let me know how that works for you :)

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser

Comment: But how does that point to the MySQL server - the issue is that the tests try and access my built in server so I can't test my databases on MAMP

Answer (score -1):

I'd double check your mysql table within the dump

Once setup just add something like this to your tests

```
$I->seeInDatabase('users', array('name' => 'Davert', 'email' => 'davert@mail.com'));
```

Thiss will check the 'users' table and look for the row with the name & email as supplied in the array - works for me.

Comment: Yeah I know how to test that data is going in - I just don't know how to point it to my MAMP database rather than the built in MYSQL server

Comment: I'd maybe look at Google Groups.. may be some CodeCeption groups that could assist you there

Answer (score -1):

Two things—I believe—would fix this your problem

1. Make sure the module for which you are setting the database parameters is the same. **DB** is different from **Db**
2. MAMP runs its MySQL on port 8889. If you only specify `localhost` in the `dsn` string, Codeception will try to connect to a MySQL instance running on port 3306—which is MySQL's default port. Change `localhost` to `localhost:8889`

I just fixed this problem myself. Comment for further clarifications if need be.

Cheers

**EDIT**

Recently, I revisited the project which I used Codeception. This solution did not work for me. I ran into two issues

1. `Timezone Exception` You can fix this by...

   - Making sure the timezone is set correctly in your `php.ini` file, which is usually in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x/conf/`
   - AND/OR aliasing `php` to use MAMP's by doing `alias phpm="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.x/bin/php"`
2. `[Codeception\Exception\Module] (Exception in Db)` This is primarily because of the configuration of the module. I removed the port number from my configuration and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks, seems plausible will give it a whirl and let you know

Comment: This always returns a "Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8889'"

Comment: @AshleyBanks `8889` is the port on which my MAMP's MySQL server is running. If yours is not running on port 8889, this error will suffice. Check your MAMP ports in `Preferences -> Ports` and set the port accordingly. Cheers

Comment: Ironically, this stopped working for me. Did you find a fix, @AshleyBanks?